# JOIN between table and view is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that return more than 100000 rows in 15 sec. This view return a field ElementId. I have a table Elements with a primary key Id.

```
SELECT MV.ElementId 
FROM MyView MV
```

My query is very slow (> 4min) when i apply a join between the view and the table like this :

```
SELECT E.Id 
FROM MyView MV 
INNER JOIN Elements E ON E.Id = MV.ElementId
WHERE E.CustomerId = @CustomlerId
```

Why the execution time is so different between the 2 queries? How can i optimize the second query?

I use SQL Server 2014

Comment: Show us the view definition, and its table definitions, incl indexes.

Comment: have you looked at the executions plans at all? should be your first port of call.

Comment: Right click in query editor then click `display estimated execution plan`. there you can get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is depends on many factors:

1st - does this query is slow for each parameter or only for some of them?
If this query is slow only for some of them you can try OPTIMIZE FOR UKNOWN feature - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature/

2nd - Do you have any index on Elements table?
If not you can create clustered index on elementId column.

Best will be if you can share execution plan with us.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Optimization your database :
1. tunning database and table
2. create index in the table (test in mysql)

Answer (score -2):

Consider indexing MV.ElementId as well as Elements.CustomerId